# Is there a way to stop sending message for a certain interval of time after a IF CONDITION is fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So here is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready')
    
})

client.on('message', message => {


const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 15)) + 15;

if(num >= 23 && num <= 30) {
    console.log(num)
    message.channel.send("Yes")
}
else {return}



})
client.login('PzkwUUdhdnjksi-&gtndBhjudu')
```

My doubt is, when this condition is fulfilled, ie., once the **num** becomes greater than 23 and less than 30, I need the bot to stop sending message for 60 seconds. Is there a way to do this? Help me

Comment: You can use `setTimeout()` here, and also maybe remove the bot secret token from the code snippet.

Comment: The thing is I replaced the original token and replaced it with random letters and numbers. Thanks Bro for the suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you removing the login token.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a **timer** to your function in the if statement, like this

```
client.on('message', message => {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 15)) + 15;
    
    if(num >= 23 && num <= 30) {
        console.log(num)
        message.channel.send("Yes")
        let now = Date.now();
        let timeOut = now + 1000 //in milliseconds
        while (now < timeOut) {
            console.log('waiting');
        }
    }
    else {return}
});
```

Date.now() returns the number of milliseconds, counted since 1 January 1970. The while function does nothing significant, it is just JS waiting to go further.

Alternatively, **setTimeout()** might also work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple timeout function like this

`setTimeout(() => message.channel.send('this is delayed for 1 second!'), 1000)`

setTimeout takes two arguments, a callback function and time in millisecond.

I believe this would be the code that you want

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready')
    
})

client.on('message', message => {


const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 15)) + 15;

if(num >= 23 && num <= 30) {
    console.log(num)
    setTimeout(() => message.channel.send('This is delayed for 1 second'), 1000);
    message.channel.send("Yes")
}
else {return}



})
client.login('please hide your token next time');
```

one more thing, next time make sure you dont leak your BOT TOKEN like that, regenerate it ASAP :)

Comment: Thank you, and the token is not the real one, I just made up with some random character and number Lol.